# Enabled false depois de digitar

Tags: vb.net

Eu tenho um textbox com um text escrito um numero padrao e com a propriedade enabled = false, ou seja um textbox com um numero que nao pode ser alterado.

Mas criei um botao que deixa o enabled do textbox true, e com isso o numero pode ser alterado livremente.

Gostaria que depois de digitado um novo numero, o textbox voltasse a ficar com o enabled = false.

Alguem poderia me ajudar? Sabe se existe essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, segue o exemplo de como você deve fazer

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("Campo01").disabled = true;
  };
  function myFunction2() {
   document.getElementById("Campo01").disabled = false;
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p>Clique na Check para desbloquear o campo</p>

 <input type="text" id="Campo01" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="1" disabled="True">
 <input type="checkbox" name="Check01" value="Bike" onclick="myFunction2()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas como eu aplicaria este código no Visual Basic, creio que eu não tenha entendido muito bem

Comment: Não seria bom você fazer por javascript, pois em vb o comando será executado no servidor... mas caso você precise eu coloco o código do vb também.

Comment: Na verdade tem que ser em VB mesmo, mas atraves desse seu exemplo em javascript consegui achar um modo para o que eu quero no vb, seria usando um checkbox com esse codigo `If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Enabled = True
        ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            TextBox1.Enabled = False
        End If`       Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Isso mesmo garoto.... Você pode votar como útil o meu comentário também.